# Deriving Law of large numbers for renewal process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, law-of-large-numbers

Let $A(t)$ be a unit rate poisson process. I want to show that
$$\frac{A(t)}{t } \to 1 \quad \quad a.s. \quad as \ \ t \to \infty$$
I am able to show for all $n \in \mathbb N$
$$\frac{A(n)}{n } \to 1 \quad \quad a.s. \quad as \ \ n \to \infty$$

using the telescopic sum
$$A(n)=\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n }A(i)-A(i-1)$$

How do I show for non integer t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n$ denote the time when the nth renewal occurs.
Then we have
$$
\frac{S_{A(t)}}{A(t)} \le \frac t{A(t) } \le \frac{S_{A(t) + 1}}{A(t)}
$$
By the law of large number
$$
\frac{S_{A(t)}}{A(t)} \to \frac1\lambda = 1 \quad \text{as}\ t \to \infty
$$
since $A(t) \to \infty$ as $t\to\infty$.
Similarly
$$
\frac{S_{A(t) + 1}}{A(t)} = \frac{S_{A(t) + 1}}{A(t)+1}\frac{{A(t) + 1}}{A(t)} \to \frac1\lambda = 1
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{A(t)}{t} \to \lambda = 1
$$

Comment: Why does $$
\frac{S_{A(t)}}{A(t)} \to \lambda = 1 \quad \text{as}\ t \to \infty?
$$ $E(S_{A(t)}-S_{A(t)-1})=\frac{1}{\lambda }$ right?

Comment: @abc. Yes $S_{A(t)} / A(t) \to 1/\lambda$.